# Yii2 Все товары в подкатегориях

Tags: php, yii2

Вообщем такая проблема, есть проект на yii2 там есть категории с бесконечной вложенностью и такая задача вывести все товары из данной под категории и всех вложенных в неё. Вот как я получаю категорию в которую перехожу:

```
$glav_category = Category::find()->where(['translit' => $translit])->one();
```

Вот так ищу вложенные в неё категории:

```
$categorys = Category::find()->where(['parent_id' => $glav_category->id])->all();
```

И тут надо запустить какой-то цикл который проверит данные на категории на вложенность и так далее, но я хз как это сделать.По сути мне надо просто получить id всех вложенных категорий после этого получить все товары будет не сложно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить дерево категорий можно с помощью рекурсии

```
function listCategoriesAsTree($indent = '')
{
    $items = [];

    $categories = Category::find()->all();

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $items[$category->id] = $indent . $category->name;
            $items +=
                self::listCategoriesAsTree($indent . html_entity_decode('&emsp;'), $category->id);
        }

        return $items;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Оно в принципе подходит только я его немного изменил:

```
function listCategoriesAsTree($uid = 0) {
$items = [];

$categories = Category::find()->where(['parent_id' => $uid])->all();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $items[] = $category->id
        self::listCategoriesAsTree($category->id);
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Вот так.